# User is constantly logged out

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, session-cookies

On a Vaadin14 Website I had the problem, that a logged in user was constantly logged out after some time. Then I updated to Vaadin23 and hoped that the problem disappears but unfortunately it is the same. After some time the user is logged out.
Sometimes the user has to click multiple times on the login button. There is no error message on website or in the log. I have no idea why this happens.
Website template is build with https://start.vaadin.com/app.

SecurityConfiguration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/*.png")).permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/VAADIN/**")).permitAll();

        //http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/VAADIN/*")).permitAll();
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView2.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        
    }
}
```

AuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);
    @Autowired private DatabaseController dbc;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository _userRepository;
    @Autowired private MsGraphService _msGraphService;

    CustomAuthenticationProvider(UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    //@Autowired
    //private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        //user authentication by pw stored in DB
... 
        if(authResult)
        {
           //add authorities
            UserSessionInfo info = new UserSessionInfo(user, organisations, admins, mans, accesslists);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(info, password, autorities);
            logger.info("user "+user.email+" successfully logged in");
            return token;
        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("user "+user.email+" entered the wrong password");
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass)
    {
        return aClass.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Update to Vaadin23.
I tried to get more information with an VaadinServiceInitListener but there is nothing.

```
public class ServiceListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener
{
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ServiceListener.class);
    @Override
    public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
        logger.info("serviceInit");
        event.getSource().addSessionInitListener(
                initEvent -> logger.info("A new Session has been initialized!"));

        event.getSource().addUIInitListener(
                initEvent ->logger.info("A new UI has been initialized!"));
        event.getSource().addSessionDestroyListener(destroyed->
        {
            logger.info("session destroyed "+destroyed.getSource());
        });
    }
}
```

After enabling logging for org.springframework.security

```
2023-04-05 15:00:09.249 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2023-04-05 15:00:09.249 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2023-04-05 15:00:09.249 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/VAADIN/**'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/favicon.ico'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/robots.txt'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/manifest.webmanifest'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/sw.js'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/offline.html'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/icons/**'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/images/**'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/styles/**'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/h2-console/**'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/logout'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /pbmgmt' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /pbmgmt' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /pbmgmt' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /pbmgmt' doesn't match 'POST /login'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de6: RemoteIpAddress: 194.230.144.62; SessionId: null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID 594190F39E29B84F68291BDDCA5E3DCC is invalid.
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /pbmgmt at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/reguser'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/setpw'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/reguser2'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/fmopen'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.255 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/pbmgmt'; against '/test'
2023-04-05 15:00:09.256 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize FilterInvocation: URL: /pbmgmt with attributes [authenticated]
2023-04-05 15:00:09.256 DEBUG 1 --- [https-jsse-nio-8989-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar!/:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:238) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar!/:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar!/:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

**Solution**
After >100h of debugging and try&error I found out what the main problem is. I had 2 Vaadin Websites running on the same domain but on different ports. Now the problem was, that the browser uses the same Cookie for every Website on a specific domain. This means that both Sites are using the same Key in the Cookie to save the Sessionid and every Site changed the SessionId the whole time.
Solved with the following setting in application.properties:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=somewebsitecookiename
```

Comment: How much time is it? And what do you mean by click multiple time on the login button?
Is the login button shown when the session is ended or when you stay on the loginscreen for some time (5 minutes or similar?)

Comment: sometimes it occurs within 1 second after a successfull login, sometimes after minutes. Sometimes I have to click multiple times on the login button to be able to login successfully. This means that after a click on login button the login screen just reloads without an error. 
Yes after the user is logged out the page navigates automatically to the login screen.

Comment: Have you tried adding debug/trace logging to org.springframework.security to see what is going on? Also can you rule out in your browser, if you have battling cookies or something else that makes the login random (e.g. some loadballancing)?

Comment: In addition to the things above, you have a single backend server instance running, correct? Otherwise you might stumble over load balancing and (missing) session replication)

Comment: @AndréSchild yes single backend.

Comment: @cfrick ok thanks for the hint, will try to enable debug logging for org.s..security

Comment: @cfrick I added some line from logfile after enabling logging for org.sfw.security, maybe you can help here. thx